# Compilation error wile using pod2usage in perl

Tags: perl

I have a file which accepts a file as an argument and does some operation on it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Format;
use Pod::Usage;

###################
#USAGE
###################

=head1 SYNOPSIS

perl my-file.pl <log file name>

     Options:
       -help            Prints usage synopsis of this program.
       -man         Man page for this program.

Use option "-man" for extended usage help.

=head1 ARGUMENTS 

=over 1

=item 1 Log File Name

Enter name of the log file. This is a required argument.

=cut

print "\n\n";
GetOptions('help|?' => \$help, man => \$man) or pod2usage(2);
pod2usage(1) if $help;
pod2usage(-verbose => 2) if $man;
pod2usage("$0: Insufficient arguments given. Please see the usage below...")  if (@ARGV == 0);  

my $logfile = $ARGV[0];    
my $cmd;
my $n;
$cmd = q(awk '!/Jobs still running./' $logfile > temp.txt && mv temp.txt $logfile);
$n = system($cmd)
```

;

While running this file I am getting the below compilation error. Not sure what is the reason for this error as another file with similar format work fine.

```
Global symbol "$help" requires explicit package name at mv-workitem-LogWatcher.pl line 33.
Global symbol "$man" requires explicit package name at mv-workitem-LogWatcher.pl line 33.
Global symbol "$help" requires explicit package name at mv-workitem-LogWatcher.pl line 34.
Global symbol "$man" requires explicit package name at mv-workitem-LogWatcher.pl line 35.
my-file.pl had compilation errors
```

.

Answer (score 0):

You turned on [strict](https://metacpan.org/pod/strict) but failed to declare your variables.  You usually do this with [my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html).  Here's [some more about my and lexical scoping of variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-lexical-%28static%29-scoping?-Between-local%28%29-and-my%28%29?).

I'd recommend picking up a copy of [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) or [Beginning Perl](https://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting errors because you are using `use strict` in your code but you didn't declare any varibale.

To understand variable declaration read this tutorial [Variable declaration in Perl](http://perlmaven.com/variable-declaration-in-perl).